# GCC optimization of (char) pointers makes no sense

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, stm32

I am using STM32 Cube IDE version 1.8.0 for a STM32 MCU project.
Builder settings are default. It is set to "External builder".

> arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
> arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for STM32 9-2020-q2-update.20201001-1621) 9.3.1 20200408 (release)
> Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

In Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings the MCU GCC compiler command is `gcc -c` and the content of "All options" is

`-mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F412Rx -c -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS_V2 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc -I../Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb`

Pay attention to `-Os`!

Now, if I use the following code (snippet)

```
bool ESP32_WifiCommCmds_ConnectToAP ( char* ssid, char* password, char* mac )
{
    char cmd [ 96 ] = { 0 };
    char *ssidEscaped, *passwordEscaped;
    ESP32_ModuleCommCmds_EscapeSpecialCharacters ( ssid, &ssidEscaped );
    if ( ssidEscaped == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }
    ESP32_ModuleCommCmds_EscapeSpecialCharacters ( password, &passwordEscaped );
    if ( passwordEscaped == NULL )
    {
        free ( ssidEscaped );
        return false;
    }
    if ( strlen(ssidEscaped) + strlen(passwordEscaped) + strlen(mac) + 17 > sizeof(cmd) )
    {
        free ( ssidEscaped );
        free ( passwordEscaped );
        return false;
    }
    // THE FOLLOWING IF ELSE WILL GET OPTIMIZED !!!!!!
    if ( mac == NULL )
    {
        // THIS WILL GET OPTIMIZED OUT
        sprintf ( cmd, "AT+CWJAP=\"%s\",\"%s\",,,1", ssidEscaped, passwordEscaped );
    }
    else
    {
        // THIS WILL STAY
        sprintf ( cmd, "AT+CWJAP=\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",,1", ssidEscaped, passwordEscaped, mac );
    }
    free ( ssidEscaped );
    free ( passwordEscaped );
    char buffer [ 48 ] = { 0 };
    // Send cmd to ESP is left out here, for simplification
}
```

And in the business logic, call this function with only:
`success = ESP32_WifiCommCmds_ConnectToAP ( data->ssid, data->password, NULL );`

One would suggest, that the optimized code will remove the `if ( mac == NULL )` because it will always be `true`. But in fact the opposite is the case.

The issue lies in the line with `strlen(mac)` but I do not know why this is. I need explanaition because I am afraid whatever I do wrong here, will have not yet seen impact on the rest of my code.

PS: If you want to check for yourself, simply search the resulting binary to include the "AT+CWJAP=..." strings. Only one of them is in there (except you switch off the optimisations).

Comment: Which `if ( mac == NULL )` do you want to remove? There is no such condition in your code. You do not check `mac` at all but only use `strlen(mac)`

Comment: If you always pass `NULL` for `mac` you will invoke undefined behaviour when calling `strlen`.

Comment: @Gerhardh you are right. I copied the wrong code.
Also the behaviour with strlen(NULL) is correct. I did not consider that.

Comment: To check/locate whether this is due to an undefined behaviour you can say GCC not to inline functions like `ESP32_WifiCommCmds_ConnectToAP` for example and the ones used. If the problem does not appear with that, then it means GCC optimize your code based on the undefined behaviour (or actually the function parameters). If so, you need to remove the undefined behaviour. An over optimization is almost always due to undefined behaviour assuming the program logic is fine. In rare cases this is due to compiler bugs.

Comment: @JérômeRichard **An over optimization is almost always due to undefined behaviour assuming the program logic is fine**

Thank you. That would make sense.

Comment: *Also the behaviour with strlen(NULL) is correct. I did not consider that.* I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: `strlen(NULL)` is clearly undefined behavior and app may stop working in future GCC versions.

Comment: @Gerhardh it means i did not consider that, you are right.

Comment: @tilz0R I see. But the compiler left neither a warning nor an info about that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: To all of you: Everyone of you is right. A NULL check before `strlen` must be done. With that, there is no more optimization, which breaks my logic. I will wait for one of you to post your ideas as an answer and will then accept it.

Comment: Seems OK that the compiler would not issue a warning

Comment: This is a somewhat notorious gcc optimization.  If you are in an unusual situation where `strlen(NULL)` is actually supposed to do something meaningful, the optimization can be disabled with `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks`.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html.

Comment: Or, if you're in a situation where `strlen(NULL)` is not *supposed* to work, but might unexpectedly return anyway, and you need to be able to detect it, as in the famous [Linux kernel bug](https://lwn.net/Articles/342330/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `strlen(mac)` then the compiler is allowed to assume that `mac` is never null.

The reasoning is this:

A) if mac is not null, then it has assumed correctly and everything it does based on that assumption is correct.

B) if mac is null then you call `strlen(NULL)` which triggers undefined behaviour.  Since undefined behaviour means it can do absolutely anything, then anything it does must be correct.

Therefore whatever the argument when you call this function, the implementation is correct to assume that mac is not null.

Note that this all happens when compiling the implementation of the function, it never gets as far as looking at what you do in the code that calls the function, as you had supposed.

Comment: Since gcc doesn't come with its own library, it falls in something of a grey area between a hosted and freestanding implementation.  If a program for a freestanding implementation includes its own definition of `strlen` which e.g. returns 0 when passed a null pointer, then `strlen(0)` should simply return zero.  A hosted implementation would be required to include function `strlen()`, which could handle a null pointer in any way the implementer sees fit.  The Standard doesn't recognize the concept of a hosted implementation that doesn't include its own `strlen()` function.

Comment: You are saying that if srelen defined such that strlen(NULL) is defined then strlen(NULL) is defined.  I can only agree with this, however, it is not in any way connected to this question or answer.  The OP is using a combined package of gcc and newlib, where strlen(0) always indicates a mistake.

Comment: I guess @supercat is thinking of something like implementing `int mystrlen(char* x){return x==NULL?0:strlen(x);}` with what he calls _hosted implementation_.

Comment: @Luke: When the Standard says that actions it characterizes as invoking Undefined Behavior may be processed "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", that isn't offered as just a theoretical possibility.  The expectation was that if an implementation targets an environment that specifies how it will process some action for which the Standard imposes no requirements, implementations intended for low-level programming on such an environment would be expected to behave in that fashion absent an obvious or documented reason for doing otherwise.

Comment: @Luke: The term "hosted C implementation" is defined in the Standard, and part of the specification requires that it support functions like "stlren()".  The only way a compiler which does not include such functions can be properly called a "hosted C implementation" would be if it specifies that it generates code for use in an "execution environment" that supplies such functions, in which case the machine code for the operation "invoke the Standard library function strlen(x)" could be simply "make a call to function strlen(x) which must be defined in this environment".